# how can i connect two forms once i clicked button another form will show something

Tags: qt, qlabel

Hi everyone now I have three forms in my Qt,I want to click first page button and show numbers in other form. so What i can do for it ?
what i tried is :

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    loginpage.show();

 loginpage.ui->label->setText();


}
```

Comment: And why doesn't it work for you? What's the result?

Comment: it showed the loginpage.ui have no setText()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to set up a public function in your "loginpage" class that uses a string argument to set the text.

Ex.
In LoginPageClass.h

```
public slots:
    void setLabel(QString label);
```

In LoginPageClass.cpp

```
void LoginPageClass::setLabel(QString label)
{
    ui.label.setText(label);
    return;
}
```

In mainwindow.cpp

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    loginpage.show();
    loginpage.setLabel(label);
}
```

Comment: thanks for you reply, what means use string argument?

Comment: Where does this label in the last slot come from?